# Mobile Flash Light Turn on with xamarin but it is not turned,Why?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

My application is permitted to use the flash light and camera but it is not turned on. The device is a Nexus Samsung.
I try to set `FlashModeOn` but it is not working. Please help me.

```
[Activity(Label = "TurnOnLight", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    public void initCamera()
    {


        var b = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        try
        {
            if (!hasCamera)
            {

                mcamera = Camera.Open();
                hasCamera = true;

                p=mcamera.GetParameters();
                var s = p.Get(Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOn);

                   p.Set(Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch,0);
                   mcamera.SetParameters(p);


                mcamera.StartPreview();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            hasCamera = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Mojtaba, I don't know much about Android, and especially not how to work with the camera, but based on other answers I've seen around StackOverflow, your code seems to be correct. My only question is whether `hasCamera` is actually false when you start the activity and call `initCamera()`. If `hasCamera` is true, then it will never try to turn the flash on. Do you know for sure that it's getting into this block of code?

Comment: tanx for your comment, ues sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I'm using in my ZXing.Net.Mobile project, and it's working fine for me.  Keep in mind FlashModeOn is slightly different than FlashModeTorch:

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/src/ZXing.Net.Mobile/MonoForAndroid/ZXingSurfaceView.cs#L227-L267

```
public void Torch(bool on)
{
    if (!this.Context.PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FeatureCameraFlash))
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Info("ZXING", "Flash not supported on this device");
        return;
    }

    if (camera == null)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Info("ZXING", "NULL Camera");
        return;
    }

    var p = camera.GetParameters();
    var supportedFlashModes = p.SupportedFlashModes;

    if (supportedFlashModes == null)
        supportedFlashModes = new List<string>();

    var flashMode=  string.Empty;

    if (on)
    {
        if (supportedFlashModes.Contains(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch))
            flashMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch;
        else if (supportedFlashModes.Contains(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOn))
            flashMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOn;
    }
    else 
    {
        if ( supportedFlashModes.Contains(Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOff))
            flashMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOff;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(flashMode))
    {
        p.FlashMode = flashMode;
        camera.SetParameters(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MojtabaSafavi not sure what you mean

Comment: i want to turn on mobile light but my code and any code that i founded not wotking